# Is there a way to send metadata to a confluence document via a script?

Tags: python-requests, request, confluence

I have a task where I make a request to download a confluence page from a page and copy it into another with the same content, but changing it's metadata (for example the title of the page is given via a metadata) and I'd like to do this automatically, my idea of it being: the script gets certain parameters (title, author, etc.) and it puts these into the metadata of the second page. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If using ScripRUnner/Groovy Runner you can use such Groovy code:

```
def PAGE_ID = 123456
def pageManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(PageManager.class)
def page = pageManager.getPage(PAGE_ID)
def newPage = new Page()
newPage.setTitle(page.getTitle())
newPage.setBody(page.getBodyAsString())
newPage.setSpace(page.getSpace());
pageManager.saveContentEntity(newPage, null);
```